# After classifying pixels using deep learning in Arcgis, black image (only one class) is shown

Tags: deep-learning, classification, arcgis

I had taken a drone image of a village and tried to classify using a trained model. The process was successful but it returned a black mask without any contour of bunds traced on it. What could be the reason and solution?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4365.png)

Comment: Arguments padding 56;batch_size 4;thinning False
Processing Mode PROCESS_AS_MOSAICKED_IMAGE
trained using model.dlpk on GPU

Comment: Edit and upload relevant code to the question.